# Encrypted client connection in MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-aurora

I have a MySQL server. Technically, it's Amazon Aurora with MySQL compatibility and I am able to connect to it from multiple clients and then execute:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM performance_schema.session_status
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('Ssl_version','Ssl_cipher');
```

Each time I get the following response:

```sql
VARIABLE_NAME,VARIABLE_VALUE
'Ssl_cipher','ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
'Ssl_version','TLSv1.2'
```

So the connection is encrypted, but I'm unclear how. As an example, from MySQL Workbench I have set "Use SSL" to "Require" in the connection properties, but I have not provided any of the following:

- SSL CA File
- SSL Cert File
- SSL Key File

If I set Use SSL to "Require and Verify CA" or "Require and Verify Identity" then the connection fails, ostensibly because I've not provided the SSL files mentioned above. Without specifying any certificates in the connection string I'm also able to make encrypted connections from different client hosts (web server, Lambda functions, MySQL CLI, etc.) but I'm not clear on how these connections are being encrypted given that there's no certificate specified in the connection string. I'm not comfortable running something in production with it working, seemingly by accident, and hope someone can help solidify my understanding of what I'm observing.

Comment: Do you have an SSL certifricate as well?  EDIT - ooh well then you might want to get one so you can do SSL stuff.  Your stuff is probably being encrypted but not due to SSL

Comment: More specifically .. the connection is only encrypted if you use an SSL, but it seems the data you have stored in the database might be encrypted.  So the columns are encrypted, but not the pathways without the SSL.  I am getting at that you can encrypt files with or witout SSL, but to get an encrypted connection requires the https / SSL pathing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you read the relevant manual on aws aurora? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Security.html - read from  section Using TLS with Aurora MySQL DB clusters Next time olease ask questions about programming and sw development, not about database admin and cyber security. These have their dedicated sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending client certificate and key is not required by TLS.

A client certificate and corresponding key is only required, if the user was defined with `REQUIRE X509, ISSUER or SUBJECT`.

If you don't provide a CA, server certificate will be checked against the system CA, in case you have a self signed certificate the verification will fail.

If you need to use a trusted secure connection, there are only 2 ways for verification: Either the server certificate was signed by a trusted authority, or the client knows and checks the fingerprint of the certificate. Latter one is afaik only supported in MariaDB.